# E-mail app not installed, Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to send an email after a survey is done. However when I try and use this line

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email Reference Number"));
```

The dialog pops up that says `"Email Reference Number"`but below it says `"No apps can perform this action"`. I'm using a Nexus 7 and I have gmail set up.

Is there a better way to bring up the option to choose an e-mail?

Thanks

Just in case here is the full email code

```
Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SENDTO);
emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT,"Reference Number");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, Html.fromHtml("<b>Thank you for your business, here is your reference number: " + ref + "</b>"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent,"Email Reference Number"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on my Nexus 7:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
intent.setType("message/rfc822");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Reference Number");
intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,  Html.fromHtml("<b>Thank you for your business, here is your reference number: " + ref + "</b>"));
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Email Reference Number"));
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Intent.ACTION_SENDTO`, you need to call `setData()` to set an appropriate `mailto:` URI.

You can also use the `Intent.ACTION_SEND` action and specify the recipient with the `Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL` extra.